# How to return the search value which are not available in database?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose table1 has some values say ('1','2','3','C','D','E').

My query is:

```
Select T.value from table1 T where T.value in ('1','2','3','A','B','C')
```

I wanted to return 'A', 'B' one in a result row, or in a single cell.

How do I do this?

**EDIT**

According to steve's Answer, I modified it a little and it worked for me.

```
Select value from (values ('A'),('B'),('1')) table1(value)
except
Select value from (select value from table1) table1(value);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 1 row? Do you want a new object with 2 properties, a string with a delaminator like a comma, something else? What is the expected output?

Comment: Your title and description don't align. In the title you say you want to return "data that's not available" and in the question you want to return a single row. What is it? What are your expected result here?

Comment: Any, I just need to return 'A' and 'B'

Comment: So what's wrong with your query? If you just want `'A'` and `'B'` why are you passing `'1'`,`'2'`,`'3'` and `'C'` too?

Comment: @Larnu I changed the title. sorry

Comment: That doesn't help elaborate what you are after. Again, we need expected results here.

Comment: @Larnu I am searching for ('1','2','3','A','B','C') but the table does have 'A' and 'B' value so I wanted 'A' and 'B' which are not available inside table

Comment: What is wrong with the proposed solution by @SteveC ? Again, it is hard to know what you want if you do not supply expected output.

Comment: Please try creating an [mcve], you can use http://dotnetfiddle.net/ as well to check if your code can run by itself. Include the expected output and have the sample show the actual output. That might clarify the question for the rest of us.

Comment: @RitaShroff Post your expected results, you aren't making this any clearer... *" table does have 'A' and 'B' value so I wanted 'A' and 'B' which are not available inside table"* You appear to be describing a Schrödinger's table at the moment, where a table both contains and doesn't contain a value. If `'A'` and `'B'` are in the table, they can't *not* be in the table..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using rows in virtual tables

```
Select test_value from (values ('1'),('2'),('3'),('A'),('B'),('C')) table1(test_value)
except
Select test_value from (values ('1'),('2'),('3'),('C'),('D'),('E')) table1(test_value);
```

Results

```
test_value
A
B
```

Comment: Not like that SteveC. I replace table and still it shows A and B.

Comment: *"Well okay, a lil modification and it worked for me"* You should share what that is, @RitaShroff .

Comment: was testing it @SteveC